# Handle 4 For loops at once?

Tags: powershell, loops, for-loop, active-directory

## Introduction to question

I'm trying to search for the following values: `'02-08-1997'` and `'01-08-1997'` in string `$b1`. To find that value, I used searching for the starting and ending index of the values around it.

## How did I do it?

To do this I used 4 For loops, only to execute the exact same thing over and over again. I know this can be done much simpler; so far I haven't found a way to do so yet. I have to write multiple scripts like this, so I really need to find a simpler - more easy to read - way to do so.

These are 2 of the For loops I'm using:

```
$b1 = 'set-aduser -identity 3423-234-23-42-432 dorstm -replace @{ geboortedatum = 01-08-1997 } waarde_org = 02-08-1997'

For ($i = 0; $i -lt $b1InArray.Length; $i++) {
    if ($b1InArray[$i].contains("=")) {
        $e = $i
        break
    }
}


For ($j = ($e + 1); $j -lt $b1InArray.Length; $j++) {
    if ($b1InArray[$j].contains("}")) {
        $f = $j
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Thanks for your dislike and contribution to my issue.

Comment: It is hard to help you if your question is isn't very clear. That's, I assume, the reason Micha referred you to the MVCE. I will post a solution based on the assumption you want to know the indes (position) of the string you are looking for in $b1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use more of a Java solution. In Powershell you can use 'ForEach'

```
$b1 = 'set-aduser -identity 3423-234-23-42-432 dorstm -replace @{ geboortedatum = 01-08-1997 } waarde_org = 02-08-1997'

foreach ($b in $b1) {

     if ( $b -contains '=') {
        $f = $j
     }
 }
```

Note: $b in the foreach loop condition can be anything you want it to be just like $i in Java.

Comment: Very much correct JonR, I'm a Java developer and I accepted a good paying extra PowerShell role. Thanks for your reply, I'll try working with the foreach method.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at what you are setting the $b1 variable to, You would want to do $b1 = get-aduser.... Have that return all the users you want and then in your foreach loop  do the set-aduser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the index of the strings you are searching for: there's a method for that:

```
$b1.IndexOf('02-08-1997')
$b1.IndexOf('01-08-1997')
```

No need to write loops. For simple things like this .Net has a working method for you.

Comment: Gert, thanks for your reply. Although, this script is for +- 1300 end-users, each with different birthdates: meaning I can not depend the index on a certain stringvalue. The value of 01-08-1997 could be 09-11-1965 for a different user.

Comment: Well, that wasn't clear at first hand. In that case regex (regular expressions) will be your friend. Learn regex, hard at first, it will make life easier

Comment: Awesome tip, will definitely place Regex on top of my to-do list. My apoligies for asking an unclear question. Will def. keep that in mind next question I'm going to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this. This could work for you:

```
(Select-String -InputObject $b1 -allmatches -Pattern '\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}').matches.value
```

it will output all dates from your $b1 string as an array of strings. Assuming all dates have the same format like your example.
Fiddle with regex at https://regex101.com/

Comment: -Pattern, wow... Looks like a cool feature. Definitely going to use that. Thanks again!